# Raspberry Pi Kernel Compilation Problem

Tags: kernel, cross-compilation, real-time

I am trying to cross compile a raspberry Pi kernel with RT Preempt patch.
I am following this [tutorial](http://www.frank-durr.de/?p=203).

I have downloaded the latest kernel sources **rpi-4.9.13** and the corresponding rt patch **patch-4.9.13-rt11.patch.gz**

After doing the menuconfig step, when I do

```
sudo make zImage
```

I recieved the error:

```
No rule to make target
```

I read somewhere about bzImage so I tried:

```
sudo make bzImage
```

It then starts compilation but after some time it gives the following error:

```
drivers/of/configfs.c: In function ‘create_overlay’:
drivers/of/configfs.c:48:2: error: implicit declaration of function
‘of_fdt_unflatten_tree’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]  
of_fdt_unflatten_tree(blob, NULL, &overlay->overlay);   ^ cc1: some
warnings being treated as errors scripts/Makefile.build:293: recipe
for target 'drivers/of/configfs.o' failed make[2]: ***
[drivers/of/configfs.o] Error 1 scripts/Makefile.build:544: recipe for
target 'drivers/of' failed make[1]: *** [drivers/of] Error 2
Makefile:988: recipe for target 'drivers' failed make: *** [drivers]
Error 2
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong. I have been stuck at this for some time now and would really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

If you are compiling the kernel code in PC you should use a cross compiler: [raspberrypi/tools](https://github.com/raspberrypi/tools). So, after install and configure the cross compiler you can build kernel with these commands:

```
make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabihf- zImage dtbs -j4
make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabihf- modules -j4
```

You can configure the cross compiler adding it to your user PATH inside .bashrc file:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/user/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin
```

After exit and save the modifications in .bashrc, type: 'source .bashrc' to update PATH.
A nice tutorial I made: [Compiling kernel to Raspberry](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I8eHz1PqKsk). This tutorial was made to Raspberry B1, so you have to change defconfig as the version of Raspberry. Use bcmrpi_defconfig for PI 1, and bcm2709_defconfig for PI 2 and PI 3.

Comment: This is not exactly an answer to the question, which is about compiling the kernel on the Pi itself, but it is a nice alternative, and I'll upvote it anyway.

Comment: @Bex. I didn't see where he said is compiling on the PI itself. :D Anyway, compiling on the PI would not give this error.